# accessing .xls file and saving in folder for ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu

HOw do I access a .xls file and save it in a seperate folder in an ubuntu environment? 
I  found that I could do this to access " find . -type f -name '*.xls' " but how do I save it in a folder? I am new to ubuntu and any help would be appreciated ..
 thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can copy it using `cp` or move it using `mv`. For example

```
find . -type f -name '*.xls' -exec cp '{}' /path/to/folder/ \;
```

The folder must already exist.

Comment: thank you... but is it not possible to create a folder for it from here

Comment: @Venkat: Yes it is possible, but how you would do it depends on how many folders you need and how you decide which files go into which folders. Details matter.

Comment: ahem I wanted to create a folder containing the .xls files inside the same directory and this code worked " mkdir folder; find . -type f -name '*.xls' -exec cp '{}' /path/to/folder/ \; "  thank you for your speedy reply @RedGrittyBrick